# The complement of the vanishing locus of a form on a projective variety is an affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

All quasi-projective and quasi-affine varieties below will be over an algebraically-closed field $k$. I am trying to prove the following result:

> Let $W$ be a projective variety (in $\mathbb{P}^n$) and suppose that $F\in S:= S(\mathbb{P}^n):= k[x_0,...,x_n]$ is a form of degree $d>0$ s.t. $D_W(F) := W\cap D_{\mathbb{P}^n}(F)\neq \emptyset$, then $D_W(F)$ is an affine variety.

Supposedly, this is the result of composing the Veronese embedding with a linear isomorphism... which almost makes sense to me (I know it when $W = \mathbb{P}^n$), except it's not clear to me that the restriction of a regular map (namely even, an isomorphism such as the Veronese embedding) to $D_W(F)$ is still a regular map (or more specifically, even that the restriction of the Veronese embedding to $D_W(F)$ is still an isomorphism onto its image).

> Some elaboration on what I have tried.

I proved for one thing that if $n< m$ ($n,m\geq 1$), then we have a closed injection $i_{n,m}:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^m$, $a\mapsto (a_1,...,a_n,0,0,...,0)$, and this sends irreducible sets to irreducible sets (and hence sends affine varieties to affine varieties).

I think I can prove the original result above if I can show (at least in the isomorphism case) that:

> (True?) The restriction of a regular map of projective varieties $\phi:X\subset \mathbb{P}^n\to Y\subset \mathbb{P}^e$ to an open subset $A$ of $X$ with open affine image in $Y$, is still regular.

If I have this then I think I am done. Elaboration: we can let $d$ be the degree of the above form $F$, and we take the Veronese embedding $\Lambda:= \Lambda_d: (a_0:...:a_n)\to (a_0^d:a_0^{d-1}a_1:...:a_n^d)$, I know that $\Lambda( D(F)) = D(L)$, where $L$ is a linear form, and we know that $D(L)\cap Z$ is an affine variety, for any projective variety $Z\subset \mathbb{P}^e$ (moreover, I would also be using the statement that (if $W$ is as above) $\Lambda\mid_W(D(F)\cap W) = D(L)\cap W$). (The point is, that if I know that $\Lambda\mid_W$ is regular, then I think that I can prove the original result easily from there).

The problem I am running into is that I think the intersection of two affine varieties need not be irreducible, so the usual characterizations of regularity don't seem to help here.

> Elaboration on the definitions and notation I use.

If $X$ is a set, take $Map(X, \mathbb{A}^1)$ to be the $k-$algebra of maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$. If $X$ is a quasi-projective variety, and is, say, an opens subset of a projective variety $Z$ (an irreducible closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$), we consider the function field of $Z$, defined as $k(Z):=\{F/G\mid F,G\in S(Z):= \frac{k[x_0,...,x_n]}{I(Z)} \text{, $F$ and $G$ are homogeneous}\\ \text{ of the same degree $d$ and $G\neq 0$ } \}$,

and the $k-$algebra of regular functions on $X$, $\mathcal{O}_X(X):=\mathcal{O}_Z(X):=\{f\in k(X)\mid \text{for $p\in X$, $\exists F,G\in S(Z)$}\\ \text{ s.t. $F$ and $G$ are homogeneous of the same degree $d$, $f = F/G$, and $G(p)\neq 0$ }\}$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are quasi-projective varieties, then say that a map $\phi:X\to Y$ is a regular map if $\phi$ is continuous and for every open subset $U$ of $Y$, the map $\phi^*:Map(U,\mathbb{A}^1)\to Map(\phi^{-1}(U), \mathbb{A}^1)$, $f\mapsto f\circ \phi$, gives a $k-$algebra homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\to \mathcal{O}_X(\phi^{-1}(U))$.

If $X$ is a quasi-projective or quasi-affine variety and $F$ is a polynomial in $k[X]$ if $X$ is quasi-affine (or $F$ is a form in $S(X)$ if $X$ is quasi-projective), define $X_F:= D_X(F):= X\setminus Z_X(F)$ (the complement of the zero locus of $F$ in $X$).

I am fairly certain that this is equivalent (for a map $\phi:X\to Y$) to saying that there exists an open affine cover $\{V_i\}$ of $Y$, and an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ s.t. i) $\phi(U_i)\subset V_i$ for each $i$, and ii) the map $\phi^*:Map(V_i,\mathbb{A}^1)\to Map(U_i, \mathbb{A}^1)$, $f\mapsto f\circ \phi$, gives a $k-$algebra homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y(V_i)\to \mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ for each $i$ (this is what I was referring to above as "the usual characterization").

Comment: Hint: double check your definition of regularity. What does it depend on? If a map $X\to Y$ is regular at a point $x$, what *exactly* does that mean?

Comment: Can you give me a reference for where your getting your definitions from (namely a map of quasiprojective varieties being regular at a point)? I don't know that I am aware of a definition compatible with that. I don't know that's it is a rational map either.

Comment: I think you're getting things mixed up a little bit here - you're the one who said " it's not clear to me that the restriction of a regular map... is still a regular map", I'm trying to help you with that, and you haven't provided your definition. Would you please write your definition of a regular map in your post with an [edit]?

Comment: Understood. I have included the definition now. (I also included an equivalent characterization of which I was trying to make use of).

Comment: It is very difficult to read what you wrote since there is no indication of what your notations mean.

Comment: Let me add the notations later today. Actually I realized that I should just be using the definition instead of the equivalent condition and actually I think I figured it out now, so I’ll probably post an answer to my own question later today.

Comment: Now it should be clear? I am somewhat new to AG so I am not positive how universal or not certain things are, so I just defined quite a few things.